# Bubble sort an array that is randomly generated each time

Tags: javascript, arrays, bubble-sort

I'd like to bubble-sort the array that is randomly generated, each time the user presses the button. But I'm not sure how to bubble sort the array, when it is not yet defined. Can I link the array generated by the Random generator to my Bubble sort function?

Here is what I have tried:

```
var num = Array.from({length: 30}, ()=> Math.floor(Math.random() *  100));

function randomNumbers() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = num;
}

function bubbleSort(num) {
var swapped;
do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i=0; i < num.length-1; i++) {
        if (num[i] > num[i+1])  {
            var temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[i+1];
            num[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped);  

bubbleSort(num);
document.write(num);

}
```

Comment: not sure I understand your point completely, but for the basics: you have a `variable` named `num` on the top, later you defined `bubbleSort` function that receives an `argument` named also `num`, these aren't the same thing! Your function seems to be fine, the only thing is that you need to move `bubbleSort(num)` and `document.write(num)` to outside the curly brace, as now it's inside the function.

Comment: When you call `bubleSort(variable)` the variable you pass to it will be the one that you have access inside the function via the argument you defined (which is named `num`). Hope it's a bit clear!

Comment: Ok, understand. Thank you. But then how can I bubble sort the array that I am generating with the randomNumbers function?

Comment: `randomNumbers` function isn't generating any array, is just sets the `html` value using the `num` you created before.

Comment: made a small example sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-hooks-i0j1y?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Ah yes! That is what I meant! Thank you so much!